# Sort and delete duplicates in multidimensional array

Tags: powershell

I have an multidimensional Array and want to sort it by the date and delete the duplicate entries (by date).

```
$arrayPlaces = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
```

and that is how the Array looks like:

```
$arrayPlaces.Add(($mailBarcodeInformation[2], $mailScannedStart.Substring(22), "", "", "", "", "", ""))
```

The empty fields are filled later. The second field `$mailScannedStart.Substring(22)` is the time and the Array should be sorted by that and the duplicates should also be removed.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to add a custom object into an array and use the buit-in cmdlet `sort -unique`. It's much more readable:

```
$arrayPlaces = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
#.........
$arrayPlaces.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
    barcode = $mailBarcodeInformation[2]
    time = $mailScannedStart.Substring(22)
    foo1 = ''
    foo2 = ''
    foo3 = ''
}) >$null
#...........
$sorted = $arrayPlaces | sort time -Unique
```

---

---

However, since you already use a .NET class you can switch to a fast .NET SortedDictionary, which automatically sorts and deduplicates the collection when items are added:

```
$arrayPlaces = [Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[string,array]]@{}
```

Adding and overwriting the old value:

```
$key = $mailScannedStart.Substring(22)
$arrayPlaces[$key] = $mailBarcodeInformation[2], $key, "", "", "", "", "", ""
```

Checking for presence of an item using its key:

```
if ($arrayPlaces.ContainsKey($key)) { ....... }
```

Removing:

```
[void]$arrayPlaces.Remove('foo')
```

Accessing:

```
$items = $arrayPlaces['foo']
$item = $arrayPlaces['foo'][0]
```

Enumerating (faster):

```
foreach ($items in $arrayPlaces.Values) {
    # .........
}
```

Enumerating/pipelining (slower):

```
$arrayPlaces.Values | foreach { $_[0] = $_[1] + $[2] }
```